# Selecting row with highest ID based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

In SQL Server 2008 R2, suppose I have a table layout like this...

```
+----------+---------+-------------+
| UniqueID | GroupID | Title       |
+----------+---------+-------------+
|    1     |    1    | TEST 1      |
|    2     |    1    | TEST 2      |
|    3     |    3    | TEST 3      |
|    4     |    3    | TEST 4      |
|    5     |    5    | TEST 5      |
|    6     |    6    | TEST 6      |
|    7     |    6    | TEST 7      |
|    8     |    6    | TEST 8      |
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to select every row with the highest UniqueID number, for each GroupID.  So according to the table above - if I ran the query, I would expect this...

```
+----------+---------+-------------+
| UniqueID | GroupID | Title       |
+----------+---------+-------------+
|    2     |    1    | TEST 2      |
|    4     |    3    | TEST 4      |
|    5     |    5    | TEST 5      |
|    8     |    6    | TEST 8      |
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Been chomping on this for a while, but can't seem to crack it.

Many thanks,

Comment: Updated to include DB type - SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With  SQL-Server as rdbms you can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT UniqueID, GroupID, Title,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY GroupID
                               ORDER BY UniqueID DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT UniqueID, GroupID, Title
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

This returns exactly one record for each `GroupID` even if there are multiple rows with the highest `UniqueID` (the name does not suggest so). If you want to return all rows in then use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Here you can see all functions and how they work: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: Would using WITH be faster than a nested SELECT?

Comment: Both should have the same performance. The main advantage of the Common Table Expression (when not using it for recursive queries) is encapsulation, instead of having to declare the sub-query in every place you wish to use it, you are able to define it once, but have multiple references to it.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because for the reason stated, encapsulation was exactly what I needed to fit this query into the bigger picture - though Royi Namirs answer also worked well out of context.  Really appreciate the help guys - thanks to all for your answers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  He thinks he can use it everywhere in the document. ( he think it is a reference ) well - it is not. and it can only be used right after the CTE decleration ( as you know). you should clear it to him.  personally i wouldnt use CTE . CTE is commonly used when multi referencing at the same query. ( not whenever you want) , and ofcourse in recursive cte.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You can concat multiple CTE's and reference the other CTE in the final query. MSDN: "Using a CTE offers the advantages of improved readability and ease in maintenance of complex queries. The query can be divided into separate, simple, logical building blocks. These simple blocks can then be used to build more complex, interim CTEs until the final result set is generated."

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes I know that's not what i meant. I meant this : `select * from cte; select 1; select * from cte --bang`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT uniqueid,  groupid,  title, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( partition BY groupid ORDER BY uniqueid DESC) AS rn 
        FROM   table) a 
WHERE  a.rn = 1
```

Comment: Really appreciate all the answers in super quick time - many thanks. Can anyone tell me which of the answers is deemed most efficient?

Comment: @Simon: you could benchmark them. Smart query optimisers/planners would create the same plan for all given solutions. (in all other cases, my solution could be the fastest)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not mentioned any RDBMS, this statement below will work on almost all RDBMS. The purpose of the subquery is to get the greatest `uniqueID` for every `GROUPID`. To be able to get the other columns, the result of the subquery is joined on the original table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  GroupID, MAX(uniqueID) uniqueID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   By GroupID
        ) b ON a.GroupID = b.GroupID
                AND a.uniqueID = b.uniqueID
```

In the case that your RDBMS supports Qnalytic functions, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT uniqueid,  groupid,  title
FROM   
(
SELECT uniqueid,  groupid,  title, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groupid 
                           ORDER BY uniqueid DESC)  rn 
FROM   tableName
) x
WHERE  x.rn = 1
```

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` generates sequential number which you can filter out. In this case the sequential number is generated on `groupid` and sorted by `uniqueid` in descending order. The greatest `uniqueid` will have a value of `1` in `rn`.

Comment: Thank you... +1 for explaining how the row number part works. I had wondered but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table tt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM the_table nx
    WHERE nx.GroupID = tt.GroupID
    AND nx.UniqueID > tt.UniqueID
    )
    ;
```

- Should work in any DBMS (no window functions or CTEs are needed)
- is probably faster than a sub query with an aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple:

```
select * from test2
where UniqueID in (select max(UniqueID) from test2 group by GroupID)


Considering:

create table test2
(
UniqueID numeric,
GroupID numeric,
Title varchar(100)
)

insert into test2 values(1,1,'TEST 1')
insert into test2 values(2,1,'TEST 2')
insert into test2 values(3,3,'TEST 3')
insert into test2 values(4,3,'TEST 4')
insert into test2 values(5,5,'TEST 5')
insert into test2 values(6,6,'TEST 6')
insert into test2 values(7,6,'TEST 7')
insert into test2 values(8,6,'TEST 8')
```